# How to download oracle okvja library to java code - without installing okv server

Tags: java, maven

I want to use this oracle package https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/key-vault/21.1/okvja/oracle/okv/kmip/package-summary.html

But cannot see anywhere a jar I can download.

What is the way to use this package on my code?

Update: The guide says it can be download from an oracle key vault server. but I try to found a place to download without installing the server that is not a simple installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the package is just for oracle key vault users.

1. Access the Oracle Key Vault management console from the endpoint on
   which you wish to deploy the SDK. The login page to the Oracle Key
   Vault management console appears.
2. Do not log in. Click the Endpoint
   Enrollment and Software Download link below the Login button.
3. Download Software Development Kit

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/key-vault/21.3/okvdv/setting-oracle-key-vault-sdk.html#GUID-884A8A4D-7D3C-417A-8BB2-3E25F7ED55DE

Comment: yes but I couldn't find "Oracle Key Vault management console"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/key-vault/21.3/okvag/okv_endpoints.html#GUID-0CBF9EF8-12EB-4BEF-9FF3-1AF4BAD929B9 13.2.1

Answer (score 1):

In my research I found this oracle documentation page, speaking about the Oracle Key Vault SDK and a download page, I think this may solve your problem.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/key-vault/21.3/okvdv/setting-oracle-key-vault-sdk.html

To found the console login screen, try this link below, I think it is very explanatory:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50341_01/doc.1210/e41361.pdf

The page 44 has some information that looks like important

[image: login-screen]

Comment: yes but I couldn't find "Oracle Key Vault management console"

Comment: Answer updated, I hope it helps!

Comment: looks like its not a simple installation: "Oracle Key Vault: A Software Appliance
Oracle Key Vault is packaged as a software appliance and delivered as an ISO package,
which must be installed onto its own dedicated server.
This software appliance consists of a preconfigured operating system, an Oracle
database, and the Oracle Key Vault application.
See Also: "Oracle Key Vault Deployment Architecture" on page 2-7
System Requirements
Because it is a software appliance, remember that when you install Oracle Key Vault,
the installation removes any existing software on a server."

Comment: Yeah, you have to install the iso server and so on, it's more complicated than I thought